# What to do now? update just after install

Tags: updates

```
Configuration file '/etc/psd.conf'
 ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
 ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** psd.conf (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ? n 

1421086511166   addons.repository   WARN    Unknown type id when parsing addon: 5
1421086511170   addons.repository   WARN    Unknown type id when parsing addon: 5
1421086512463   addons.update-checker   WARN    Update manifest for {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} did not contain an updates property
1421086512713   addons.update-checker   WARN    Update manifest for ubufox@ubuntu.com did not contain an updates property

No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:000] Cpu: 6.37.5, x4, 2399Mhz, 3753MB
[000:000] Computer model: Not available
[000:000] Browser XEmbed support present: 1
[000:000] Browser toolkit is Gtk2.
[000:001] Using Gtk2 toolkit
```

Comment: What did you do? Did you do anything after installation? Please add more details rather than just pasting a block of output.

Answer (score 13):

It means that a package update contains a newer version of a configuration file, but the package manager doesn't want to overwrite the changes you made to the old version. Therefore it invokes the program [`ucf(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/ucf.1.html), which gives you the choice to either

1. overwrite the old file (<kbd>N</kbd> or <kbd>O</kbd>) or
2. retain the old file (<kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>I</kbd>).

In both cases the other version will be saved to a file with the respective suffix `*.ucf-old` or `*.ucf-new`, which gives you the chance to later inspect the differences and change, revert, and/or update things according to your needs. `*.ucf-dist` holds the original content of the configuration file in the previous package version (before you changed it).

The final two options (<kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd>) allow you to inspect the changes or the larger “situation” before making a decision. When you exit the diff viewer or the shell, you'll return to the same dialogue.